# what is the meaning of "type loop" in the asoundrc file?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, libalsa, libasound

I am new to ALSA and its userspace configuration. I saw one pcm device in my asoundrc like below

```
pcm.myalsadev{
    type loop
    device 0
    ipc_perm 0660
    ipc_gid audio
    subdevice 0
    rate 16000
    channels 1
    format S16_LE
}
```

What is the meaning of plug-in type "loop" ? I checked [this](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#) document but i cant see any expiation.

I know what is the meaning of the below configuration. Here they are using snd-aloop Linux driver to implement a loopback device, and it is same as hw:Loopback,0,0.  Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

```
pcm.myDev{
    type hw
    card "Loopback"
    device 0
    subdevice 0
    rate 16000
    channels 2
    format S16_LE
}
```

is both the configuration are same and just an another way of representation ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `loop` is not one of the built-in plugins. Where does this entry come from?

Comment: @CL. This is an entry from asound.conf file ,shipped along with a custom HW BSP. if loop is not a built-in plugin , how can i find more info on this ?

Comment: Ask whoever sold you the BSP.